# AutoHotKey Macro not working

Tags: macros, autohotkey

Hi all i have this piece of code that cant get it to work, please need an hand.

```js
    portal(){
    portalCommand:
     BlockInput On
     SendInput {i}
     Sleep 2
     MouseClick, right, 1775, 795
     SendInput {i}
     Sleep 2
     MouseClick, left, 955, 380
     BlockInput Off
     return
    }
```

The problem here i dont know why is not sending or it does to fast input I then Right Click input i again and left click, any sugestions please?

Comment: What is supposed to happen?  What is `{i}`?  Is that a variable?  If you are only sending the character "i" do it like this: `SendInput i` and btw the Sleep is `2 milliseconds` perhaps you want 2 seconds, like this: `Sleep 2000` Well, let us know . . .

Comment: so kind of you Blauhirn you know not all the eople in this world knows english may be you should think before judge so easy and try to give a good answer not only touch the balls with your stupidity

Comment: @AlinSerban Your comment is rude and offensive and not in character with this site.

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment:

```
portal(){
portalCommand:
    BlockInput On
    SendInput i
    Sleep 2000
    MouseClick, right, 1775, 795
    SendInput i
    Sleep 2000
    MouseClick, left, 955, 380
    BlockInput Off
    return
}
```

Comment: hoped a positive answer this is not helping in any way, but thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

i forgot to mention that im bad at programming is just a hobby and need it for a game to open inventory when task"{i}" is pressed about sleep you are right i have made my home work in the mean time and read about autohotkeys and stuff and i got the perfect working result thanks anyway :) here is my working code that is what i wanted and i will wxplain aftewards (sry for my english guys i think is not so good i have not study english just learned on the way:)

```js
    portal(){
portalCommand:
        BlockInput On
  ;Pressing Space if any inventory is open
        Send {space}
        Sleep 50
  ;Opening Inventory
        SendInput {i}
  Sleep 200
  ;Move the mouse to a specific location
  MouseMove, 1770, 790
  Sleep 400
  ;Pressing Mouse Right Button
        Send, {RButton}
        Sleep 400
  ;Move the mouse to a specific location
  MouseMove, 600, 370
  Sleep 400
  ;Pressing Mouse Left Button
  Send, {LButton}
        BlockInput off
 return
}
```

The give up code is a solution for me that actually works without any issue and it does send spacebar (that is the game setup to close any inventory opened) then sends "i" key to open the inventory of the character and goes to defined location making righ click on town portal scroll and after that goes back to defined location and left click on it to enter to the portal (that means going to town) the position is based on the monitor max resolution so the coordinates can be adjusted for anyone needs in case someone else need or whant to use this code ;)